# Bash script giving Illegal number error

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting an error after I enter into the 15th line...
Why? I've already tried with ', ", `... Nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
echo "Necessita de 1 argumento! (diretorio)\nPor favor, indique um diretório como argumento."
echo "\n"
echo "Prima qualquer tecla para continuar..."
read naoquerosaber
exit 69
else
echo "Diretorio: $1"
ficheiros=`ls -l $1  | wc -l`
echo "O Diretorio $1 tem $ficheiros ficheiros\n\n"
echo "Quer saber quantos ficheiros escondidos tem?\n1-Sim \t2-Não"
read resposta
if [ "$resposta" -eq "S" -o "$resposta" -eq "s" ]; then
escondidos=`ls -la $1 | wc -l`
escondidos=$(( escondidos-ficheiros ))
echo "Tem $escondidos escondidos ($(( ficheiros+escondidos ))) no total."
exit 0
fi
if [ "$resposta" -eq "N" -o "$resposta" -eq "n" ]; then
echo "Obrigado e Volte Sempre!"
read naoquerosaber
exit 0
else
echo "Opa... Ou Sim ou sopas..."
exit 69
fi
fi
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It would be useful if you (a) indicated line 15 (the second `if` line?) and (b) the exact copy-pasted error message.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974586/shell-script-awk-syntax-error#comment63395432_37974586

Comment: `-eq` is for comparing numbers, `=` is for comparing strings.